# The difference of a URL for href vs URL for src

Tags: html, pdf, href

I have these two lines of code one after the other - the embedded pdf works fine. When I click on the pdf link I get a 404 not found. The URLs are the exact same. What is the problem?

```
<embed src="./assets/connerschiller.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px" />
<a target="_blank" href="./assets/connerschiller.pdf">View Resume</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not used embed but Iframe is used for embedding pdf documents...
Here is some example below...

```html
<iframe src="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"  width="100%" height="600px" ></iframe>
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf">View Resume</a>
```

Also the **404 error** you are facing is because the pdf is might be saved on some location other than the website files folder...
If you are facing this issue on localhost then it might be due to files or drive privilege or try checking the pdf name is correct or not....

Comment: What is mind-boggling is that I ONLY get the 404 error when I try the pdf link, but the pdf shows up without error on the page in the embed, and I am using the same exact URL for both the embed and the a tag.

Comment: Can you tell which browser are you using?

Comment: Using chrome browser

Answer (score -1):

An href is the link that your text will go to. So in this case, "View Resume" goes to the .pdf file. The href will add ./assets/connerschiller.pdf to your url. Try removing the "." and it should work

Comment: tried removing "." and tried removing "./", neither made a difference